Google Home Test Suite: Query after 'Close the Gate' failed catching openPercent:100 instead of openPercent: 0
Good day to everyone!
I have an issue with Google Home Test Suite.
I'm testing a OpenClose Gate trait and i'm able to pass successfully these tests:

Open the Gate
Query after 'Open Gate'
Check Report State and Query discrepancy
Close the Gate

At this point, test's failed into these steps:

Query after 'Close the Gate'

Expected state to include:
{"xOneOf":[{"openPercent":0},{"openState":{"xArrayToInclude":{"openPercent":0,"openDirection":"xAny"}}}]}, actual state: {"online":true,"openPercent":100}: expected false to be true

- Check Report State and Query discrepancy

State 'openPercent' differs: queried '100' on 2024-09-26T09:31:00.243491Z, reported '0' on 2024-09-26T09:31:34.302809Z: expected false to be true

In my cloud service, ReportStateAndNotification returned success 200 with {Online:true OpenPercent:0} as Devices.States of homegraph.ReportStateAndNotificationDevice when my Gate is closed.
I'm expecting on Test Suite to pass also the "Query after 'Close the Gate'" and "Check Report State and Query discrepancy" with google state: {"online":true,"openPercent":0}

Thanks for sharing this. We are suggesting below steps to better troubleshoot the issue.

Use the HomeGraph Viewer tool to confirm that the state of the gate is correctly updated after the gate is closed. Ensure that the correct state is reflected in the HomeGraph before the test queries it again. This will help you determine if the problem is with the state update or the timing of the query.
In your case, the test is querying the state too soon after closing the gate. Increasing the timeout between the state change and the query could allow enough time for the state to propagate through your system and reach Google’s HomeGraph. Try increasing the Report State timeout within Test Suite beyond 20 seconds to give the system more time to process the change.

Let us know how it goes.
